# Python script to parse a config file

Tags: python, haproxy, configparser

Newbie to python here. I'm in  need of adding back end and front ends servers to the haproxy.cfg file and do a graceful reload via a python script. Could some of you point me in the right direction. If you include comments in the code it will immensely help me to understand faster.

Below is a sample block that I want to send in to the cfg, possibly based on raw_input([arg])

```
frontend fe:some_fe:bind:yyyy
        mode tcp
        bind x.x.x.x:yyyy name some_name
        use_backend be:some_be:x.x.x.x:yyyy

backend be:some_be:x.x.x.x:yyyy
mode http
        balance roundrobin
        server  x.x.x.x:yyyy check port yyyy 
        server  x.x.x.x:yyyy check port yyyy
```

Some notes- x.x.x.x signifies an ip and yyyy a port.

Please help! Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You could refer to the [pyhaproxy](https://github.com/imjoey/pyhaproxy) library, which could parse the haproxy config file and write back after some changes.

Answer (score 0):

> Read Python » 3.6.1 Documentation [6.1.4. Template strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#template-strings)

Edit your Question accordingly, e.g. replace _fe:some_fe_ with **fe:${some_fe}**

> Read Python » 3.6.1 Documentation [argparse.html#module-argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#module-argparse)

Edit your Question and append the commandline you want to use and your `argparse` code to work with.

Comment: Thanks so much @stovfl. This should work but I'm wondering if I could varibalise this a little more. For an instance "fe" as a variable and <some_fe> as it's value being passed on? Further string formatting(spaces, tabs, etc) should look exactly like this. PLease if you have the solution try to post everything cos I'm a learner :)

`code`frontend fe:<some_fe>:bind:<yyyy>
        mode tcp
        bind <x.x.x.x>:<yyyy> name <some_name>
        use_backend be:<some_be>:<x.x.x.x>:<yyyy>`code`

Comment: thanks. I was looking for a faster way to understand but guess I'm gonna have to read the documentation and figure things out myself. WIll do and thanks.

Comment: @bindo: You are wrong, I figure things out for you. You have to read the Documentation to confirm that's what you want.

Comment: There is no need to switch outside. You can edit your Question and add your code you have so far. I advise you to get it running.